# Composer issue: doctrine/annottations v1.6.0 requires php^7.1

Tags: phpspreadsheet

#### What is the expected behavior?

Installation using composer on XAMPP using php v5.6

#### What is the current behavior?

Run from the terminal, I experience the following error

Composer error:
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
-doctrine/annotations v1.6.0 requires php^7.1 -> your PHP version (5.6.23) does not satisfy that requirement

#### What are the steps to reproduce?

> composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet

#### Which versions of PhpSpreadsheet and PHP are affected?

PhpSpreadsheet-1.3.1 and PHP 5.6.23

How to resolve? PhpSpreadsheet documentation says it can be used with Php v5.6 and above.